# Installing the SourceDialog Plugin on CKeditor 4

Tags: ckeditor4.x

I have CKeditor 4 working fine; but I needed to add the 'source' button so we can edit in HTML.  This is not an inline version, it's in the CMS for editing page content.

I pasted the plugins into the plugins directory for Sourcedialog, Dialog, DialogUI and also Sourcearea.

My config.js now reads:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {


config.extraPlugins = 'savebtn';//savebtn is the plugin's name
config.saveSubmitURL = 'ajax-wysi-next.cfm';//link to serverside 
script to handle the post
config.extraPlugins = 'sourcedialog';
config.extraPlugins = 'sourcearea';

config.extraPlugins = 'dialog';
config.extraPlugins = 'dialogui';
};
```

I am not seeing the Source button appear, even after clearing cache.

Do I need to do anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this got fixed like this:

Install the SourceDialog plugin and the plugins it depends on (Dialog, DialogUI).

Change config.js to have references to them:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'sourcedialog';
config.extraPlugins = 'dialog';
config.extraPlugins = 'dialogui';
```

Then, go to the page where you have the CKeditor installed and change it to read:

```
extraPlugins: 'savebtn, sourcedialog',
```

The important thing being that you put the plugins in this same field, separated by a comma, and NOT do an 'extraPlugins' line for each plugin.

Now both the Source button and my Save button are working fine.
Hope this helps others!